# A/C voltage in the air?

Tags: ac, grounding, wiring, bad-wiring

I've been building a counter top dishwasher and just noticed that my sink is kind of grounded, around 30Megaohms resistance but 120V.
While checking that I also noticed the air near metal in my apartment has between 10-30V AC to the positive plug. Its enough to turn on small leds and confuse me to no end! I have no fancy technology, this is an old apartment with some copper and some pvc pipe.
My cheaper multimeter shows the same, and no current, this meters fuse is blown for current. Should i be worried/ Is this affecting my power bill?

[image: Airborne AC]

[image]

Comment: When you say "Its enough to turn on small leds" where are you connecting the LED? Can you show us a picture of how the LED is connected when you see it turn on?

Comment: It's the led on a (unplugged) 5v relay. With the AC positive connected to the relay common, when its DC supply negative line gets near the sink it starts flickering.

Comment: When i actually touch this little 5V led to my sink I can hear an arc/humming from the back of the sink.

Comment: Google "Phantom voltage".    This is a phenomenon caused by the uber-high impedance of your digital voltmeter.   Connect about 100k resistor across those same points, bet the voltage drops to basically zero.  Forget the effect on your power bill --- If it doesn't drop to zero volts after doing what I suggest, call an electrician immediately, because your plumbing is electrically live and you literally could die.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the Phantom voltage rabbit hole, I am still seeing the same readings with 100k on my probe, but now im thinking that is my capacitance, and the fact that my sink is connected to ground. But since my dishwasher has A/C hot on a relay near the sink, I guess i need to be very careful!

Comment: Your meter is connected to the live phase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any major  bit of architectural metal (building frame, metal pipes,
siding or roofing) is expected to be bonded to ground.   By making
a measurement from the HOT pin of a socket, you are measuring
capacitive coupling of the meter (and the hand holding the meter)
to that grounded metal.   That's not a useful measurement.

Since your depicted outlet is a GCFI  box, it's not enough
current to deliver a shock (or it'd trip the circuit OFF).
It doesn't indicate any 'voltage in the air' other than
the zero-volt grounded bits of the building.  The power for that tiny
trickle of AC current came through the outlet's HOT wiring.

Safety significance attaches to CURRENT measurement (not voltage with
zero load) between touchable metal and the ground pin of
the  power socket, with a human-body load attached (about
1000 ohms is typical).  The HOT socket contact is not touchable, one hopes.

For safety, I'd recommend not leaving any probe in the power
socket.

Comment: I like this answer, my plumbing is old and most likely all grounded. Since i only hear the sink hum when i short it to HOT and if i grab my meter the voltage goes up by a few V's,  it makes sense. But sorry I'm confused about what you mean by zero-volt grounded bits. I also notice the gain amplification on this meter picks up 60hz from a few feet away.

Comment: The ambient fields in a building are caused by static, and by "hot" wires in the walls, and in power cords.   The voltages are (by convention) relative to ground, which is wired to all the third-prong connections in all your outlets.   If you measure 60 Hz, it's the hot wires that cause that, are  you speaking of 'a few feet away' from all the wires in walls and power cords?

Comment: I understand what you meant now, great explanation. I'm only getting a few feet of range for readings on outlets that are paired with a light switch, when that light switch is on. So its hearing a flow from the switch contact, it only happens when I use the meters noise filter.